# CSV Dynamic FileName in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, sharepoint

¡Good morning! I working with SharePoint and I will need a CSV Report with the data for Version History and Recycle Bin. The question is: Its possible create an CSV with dynamic name?

Like `[site].[date]_versions.csv`

Thanks in advance and greetings

If its possible, the result or the name for CSV its created with the name of the Sites and the actual date.

Comment: Pease copy and paste the code you are trying to make work into the question as text. If you need to hire a programmer, you might try https://stackoverflow.co/talent/